# NGRX - How to update a field in an object in an array by reducer?

Tags: angular, state, ngrx, reducers

How can I update a field in an array by reducer? I tried this:

```
const customers = state.filteredCustomers;
for (const customer of customers) {
    for (const addr of customer.addresses) {
         addr.selected = false;
    }
}

return {
    ...state,
    filteredCustomers: customers,
};
```

But it throws an error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'selected' of object '[object Object]'
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to take a copy of each level of the state. It's here where it can become awkward to update nested state for x levels deep. That's why I would encourage [normalizing your state](https://timdeschryver.dev/posts/normalizing-state).

Basically, you will have to loop over the customers and copy the properties, next you will have to do the same for the adresses and set selected to false.

```
return {
    ...state,
    filteredCustomers: state.filteredCustomers.map(c => ({
       ...c,
       addresses: c.adresses.map(a => ({...a, selected: false})
    })
};
```

A second option would be to use immer, [Clean NgRx reducers using Immer](https://timdeschryver.dev/posts/clean-ngrx-reducers-using-immer)
There's a library that does this for the `createReducer` function in NgRx 8 - https://github.com/timdeschryver/ngrx-etc/#mutableon. Via this approach you use the code snippet posted in the question.

Comment: But my state is an array of instances of classes. this makes them an object without any method

Comment: Great info on state normalization and usage of immer.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be one of mutating some immutable reference. I would try something like this.

```
    const customers = state.filteredCustomers;

    const updatedCustomers = customers.map( customer => ({
...customer, addresses: customer.addresses.map( address => ({ ...address, selected: false 
}));

    return {
        ...state,
        filteredCustomers: { ...state.filteredCustomers, ...updatedCustomers  },
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map to return a new array of customer with the updated values.

```
return {
  ...state,
  filteredCustomers: customers.map(customer => {
    // Either use a second map or another loop
    for (const addr of customer.addresses) {
      addr.selected = false;
    }
    return customer;
  })
};
```

Comment: It does not work for the `addr.selected = false;` again! even used the map.

Answer (score 0):

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

and in your code use

```
const tags: IAreaTag[] = _.cloneDeep(department.tags);
```

and then return the constant

So In your code

```
const customers = _.cloneDeep(state.filteredCustomers);
```